# Postgresql maintainenace queries fail with foreignkey violation

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, maintenance

I maintain a Django app with a postgresql backend, where users post interesting URLs (links) and then either leave replies under these or upvote/downvote them. All this is done via 4 postgresql tables `links_link`, `links_publicreply`, `links_vote` and `links_seen` (`links_seen` keeps track of which `publicreplies` were seen by a user; the other 3 tables do what their names indicate).

I'm running maintenance queries whereby I'm deleting mature records from `links_publicreply` and related rows from `links_seen`. The queries go like so:

```
begin;
DELETE FROM links_seen WHERE which_reply_id in (SELECT id FROM links_publicreply where "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days');
DELETE FROM links_publicreply WHERE "submitted_on" < now() - interval '7 days';
commit;
```

This fails with the error:

> ERROR:  update or delete on table "links_link" violates foreign key
>   constraint "links_vote_link_id_fkey" on table "links_vote" DETAIL: 
>   Key (id)=(2207250) is still referenced from table "links_vote".

I've grappled with this for over 10 days, but can't fix it (beginner DBA here). Can anyone point out (i) what the problem is, (ii) what do I need to do to fix it so that my maintenance queries start working (I'm essentially just deleting `publicreplies` older than 7 days)? An illustrative example would be nice. Thanks in advance!

---

These tables are described as follows. **links_link**:

```
                                     Table "public.links_link"
     Column      |           Type           |                        Modifiers                        
-----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_link_id_seq'::regclass)
 description     | text                     | not null
 submitter_id    | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 rank_score      | double precision         | not null
 url             | character varying(250)   | not null
 cagtegory       | character varying(25)    | not null
 image_file      | character varying(100)   | 
 reply_count     | integer                  | default 0
 device          | character varying(10)    | default '1'::character varying
 latest_reply_id | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "links_link_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_link_submitter_id" btree (submitter_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_link_submitter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitter_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "publicreplyposter_link_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_publicreply" CONSTRAINT "links_publicreply_answer_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (answer_to_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_vote" CONSTRAINT "links_vote_link_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (link_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

(END)
```

**links_vote**:

```
Table "public.links_vote"
  Column  |  Type   |                        Modifiers                        
----------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('links_vote_id_seq'::regclass)
 voter_id | integer | not null
 link_id  | integer | not null
 value    | integer | 
Indexes:
    "links_vote_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_vote_link_id" btree (link_id)
    "links_vote_voter_id" btree (voter_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_vote_link_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (link_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_vote_voter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (voter_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

**links_publicreply**:

```
                                      Table "public.links_publicreply"
     Column      |           Type           |                           Modifiers                            
-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_publicreply_id_seq'::regclass)
 submitted_by_id | integer                  | not null
 answer_to_id    | integer                  | not null
 submitted_on    | timestamp with time zone | not null
 description     | text                     | not null
 category        | character varying(20)    | not null
 seen            | boolean                  | not null
 abuse           | boolean                  | not null
 device          | character varying(10)    | default '1'::character varying
Indexes:
    "links_publicreply_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_publicreply_answer_to_id" btree (answer_to_id)
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id" btree (submitted_by_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_publicreply_answer_to_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (answer_to_id) REFERENCES links_link(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_publicreply_submitted_by_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (submitted_by_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "links_seen" CONSTRAINT "links_seen_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "links_link" CONSTRAINT "publicreplyposter_link_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (latest_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**links_seen**:

```
                                      Table "public.links_seen"
     Column     |           Type           |                        Modifiers                        
----------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                  | not null default nextval('links_seen_id_seq'::regclass)
 seen_status    | boolean                  | not null
 seen_user_id   | integer                  | not null
 seen_at        | timestamp with time zone | not null
 which_reply_id | integer                  | 
Indexes:
    "links_seen_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "links_seen_seen_user_id" btree (seen_user_id)
    "links_seen_which_reply_id" btree (which_reply_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "links_seen_seen_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (seen_user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "links_seen_which_reply_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (which_reply_id) REFERENCES links_publicreply(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: "the other 3 tables do what their names indicate" could you explain this more?  To me, the names imply that links_link should be the parent table (either directly or indirectly) of all the others, but instead it is the child table of links_publicreply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete from `links_publicreply`, it cascades that to delete child rows from `links_link` which would otherwise become orphaned (because the constraint is defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`).

But some of those rows being deleted in `links_link` are still referenced by rows in `links_vote`.  The constraint between `links_link` and `links_vote` is *not* defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so you get an error.  If you want to automatically delete the rows from `links_vote`, change the constraint to be `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  If that is not what you want, then it is not clear what you do want, you will have to explain it some more.

Comment: Yes. There's also another FK referencing `link_links`, from `links_publicreply`. This is also not `ON DELETE CASCADE`. This may not cause the problem now but it also could, potentially.

Comment: I actually just want to delete `publicreplies`, leaving `links` intact as they are. It's the equivalent of leaving the main content untouched, and only sanitizing the comments.